# No system images available in Android studio for automotive

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-automotive

When i try to create a AVD --> Automotive --> Polestar 2 --> After clicking on next reulsts "No System images available...."

I followed all possible things to fix it but there is no improvement.

In SDK Update suite, i have added th below add-ons:

**Name:** Polestar 2 System Image

**URL:** https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml

**Name:** Android Automotive System Images

**URL:** https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml

After adding them, i have selected polestar 2, Automotive intel... in SDK platforms (Can able to see them after checking *show package details*).

Please help how to fix it.

**Note:** For other platforms (Phone/ tablets, wear OS etc,) emulators are working fine. Only for Automotive they are not working.

Comment: A simple example code where the issue can be reproduced would be very helpful in helping you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest Android Studio Canary 4.2. It can be used alongside your current stable version. On a stable version, it didn't work for me.
The version I use: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/08/android-studio-42-canary-8-available.html

Answer (score 0):

Please find the "Polestar 2" device in "Tablet" definition, rather than "Automotive". See image below. Or you can search it in the search box above.

[image]